# Shillelagh spell on nunchaku: how does it work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons

The *Shillelagh* spell says that spell ends if the caster lets go of the club/staff or if they cast it again the original spell ends.

But the PHB mentions a monk weapon called the nunchaku which it says would be 2 clubs connected by a string.

So would the spell treat the nunchaku as 2 different clubs and only buff one half of the nunchaku? Or does *Shillelagh* buff the entire nunchaku but the buff only apply to the first club attack? *Or* does shillelagh buff both clubs for both attacks?

There is a level 4 monk in my group who has taken the Magic Initiate feat and chose druid and one of the cantrips she took was shillelagh as she uses nunchaku. I would like to know how I should implement the spell when we meet again this saturday so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes, but...

The only reference to nunchaku that is present in the Player's Handbook is in the section detailing Monk Weapons in the Monk class description.

This section (PHB p.78) mentions:

> Certain monasteries use specialized forms of the monk weapons. For example ... a club that is two lengths of wood connected by a short chain (called a nunchaku) ... Whatever the name you use for a monk weapon, you can use the game statistics provided for the weapon in chapter 5

So, using this logic, and the example used in the PHB, you would use the statistics of a club for your nunchaku.

So, your *shillelagh* spell **can** affect "both ends of the nunchaku", **as long as it is used mechanically the same as a club**, since the PHB has given license to mess around with the flavour of your monk weapons.

---

**What this means** is that you could use the nunchaku like one club, not the way you are looking for (used like two clubs, using two-weapon fighting rules) unless you are using two of them. **However**, as per the rules of the *shillelagh* spell, if you cast the spell a second time, the previous instance of the spell ends.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's how I am going to implement it during our next session unless someone else makes a better argument. thank you very much for your in depth understanding of the lore and rules it is very helpful. orz

Answer (score 13):

## No

There is no nunchaku in the PHB weapons list. The DMG says on page 41 in the chapter "Flavors of Fantasy" that a nunchaku is nothing but a flail with a japanese name. The spell says it works on "The wood of a club or quarterstaff you are holding". A nunchaku is neither. Mechanically a flail is a different entity than a club or staff and from a lore perspective, a wooden club or staff are somewhat pure, while a nunchaku has by definition a metal chain attached to both pieces of wood.

Comment: sorry for not citing page 78 in the PHB. This is my first post so I wasn't sure on proper etiquette. thank you very much for your response it is greatly appreciated. orz